# Handlebars inline css

Tags: css, handlebars.js, inline-styles

I would like to pass inline css like style="background-color: value" using handlebars.

I  have js file

```
module.exports = {
  header: 'some title',
  boxes: ["here some objects"],
  style: {
    backgroundCol: '#000',
    textCol: '#f00',
    numbersCol: '#c31d5a',
    titleSize: '28px',
    numbersSize: '42px',
  }
}
```

I use #each loop to get all the boxes and the want to pass these styles to style them.
I have tried to do it in this way:

`<div class="test" style="background-color: '{{style.backgroundCol}}'">`

What is the proper way to use inline styles, or maybe there is some way to pass this "style" object to stylesheet and use classes?

Comment: What does Handlebars compile `style="background-color: '{{style.backgroundCol}}'"` to?

Comment: Hi



`<section class="container">
      <h1 style="font-size:{{style.titleFontSize}};">{{title}}</h1>
      <div class="container__wrapper">
        {{#each elements}}
        <div class="tile" style="background-color:{{style.backgroundColor}};">
          ...
        </div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </section>`

For example <h1> throws what I want --> `style="font-size:48px;"`
But when I am in the #each loop it throws me --> `style="background-color: ;"`

@cjl750

Comment: Ok, I solve it. In the each loop I had to write for example `style="color:{{../style.numbersColor}};"` because of my data structure.